# Required custom Property

Tags: google-app-engine, properties, google-cloud-datastore, required

I create a custom `db.Property` subclass:

```
class PropertyFoo(db.StringProperty):
  def validate(self, value):
    # Yes this is a pointless validator, but please read on
    return value

  def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
    return super(PropertyFoo, self).get_value_for_datastore(model_instance)

  def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    return super(PropertyFoo, self).make_value_from_datastore(value)
```

Now I also create a `db.Model` subclass:

```
class ModelFoo(db.Model):
  foo = PropertyFoo(required=True)
```

So I test them out:

```
>>> m = ModelFoo()
# No errors :(
>>> m.foo
# No errors still
>>> print m.foo
'None' # <-- Why???
```

I should expect an error like:

```
BadValueError: Property foo is required
```

How do I make sure that my custom `Property` subclass, when it is `required`, raises a `BadValueError`? Am I missing something in my `PropertyFoo` definition?

Comment: By the way, there's no point in subclassing methods if you just call super - you can just omit them entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to call the `validate` method of the super class:

```
class PropertyFoo(db.StringProperty):
  def validate(self, value):
    super(PropertyFoo, self).validate(value) #Base implementation checks
    #Do your other check here raising BadValueError
    return value
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it just before you posted :) Kept it here so someone else might benefit :)